# Apache, use X-Forwarded-For for allow

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-authz-host

How can use X-Forwarded-For headers(my proxy ip 10.1.1.x) to allow HTTP query?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use SetEnvIf and Allow:

```
    <Location "/only_proxy/">
            SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^10\.1\.1\. proxy_env
            Order allow,deny
            Satisfy Any
            Allow from env=proxy_env
    </Location>
```

Comment: Remember that it's really easy to forge X-Forwarded-For header.

Comment: It's also reasonably easy to protect yourself from forged X-Forwarded-For headers (by stripping this header at entry points into your environment).

Comment: found this post while looking for information on how to protect against forged x-forwarded headers, would you mind pointing to a relevant doc?

Answer (score 4):

You can write a rewrite rule to redirect to 403 response.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} !(1.1.1.1|2.2.2.2)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/) to make Apache treat the X-Forwarded-For IP as the client IP.

Comment: For those who find their way here from Google: note that `mod_rpaf` is only able to make your logs useful; it does not actually affect the address used in access control decisions.  Also note that in Apache 2.4, the `mod_rpaf` functionality is provided natively by [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html).

Comment: @larsks: That is not true. I tried and it did work for me!