# Apache Alow From specific IPs behind load balancer

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing

We have an endpoint that we've locked down to be only accessible from specific IPs. We have a conf section kinda like this:

```
<Location /Foo>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 111.111.111.111 
    Allow from 111.222.333.444
    ...
</Location>
```

Now, it's gotten to the point where we need to load balance it between a couple of machines, but we still need to lock it down to only be accessible from those IPs.

So... how can I set Apache to `Allow from` the `X-Forwarded-For`?

Comment: Can't the load balancer do the security instead of Apache?

Comment: Do you need to use the normal IP authorization directives for some specific reason, or can you use another method?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a load balancer that is doing SNAT/NAPT obscuring the client IP address.

Have you seen this answer, which solves it using SetEnvIf? [Apache, use X-Forwarded-For for allow](https://serverfault.com/questions/235648/apache-use-x-forwarded-for-for-allow)

There's a comment on that answer about forging. I'd point out that:

- Someone who can reach your server directly (presumably an internal attacker) can fake the X-Forwarded-For header, so you should also lock Apache down to just the load balancer SNAT address(es).
- Your load balancer should be scrubbing X-Forwarded-For headers from incoming requests so that external attackers can't fake it.