# Why did my VPN changes to my Apache2 httpd.conf make our server public?

Tags: apache-2.2, vpn, httpd, intranet

I want our server to be available *without* LDAP login if the client is requesting through our intranet.  It appears that all intranet traffic comes through 10.0* IPs.  I modified our VirtualHost based on other httpd.confs I found online to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerName <REDACTED>

    WSGIScriptAlias / <REDACTED>

    <Directory /var/server/server>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "<REDACTED>"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPBindDN "uid=<REDACTED>,ou=<REDACTED>,dc=<REDACTED>"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "<REDACTED>"
        AuthLDAPURL "<REDACTED>"
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative On
        Require valid-user
        # I added/modified the following lines when I wanted to get rid of LDAP authentication for internal users
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all 
        Allow from 10.0
        Satisfy any
     </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**However, when I did this it make our server available from the internet without LDAP access!  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: That should do it.  Are you sure the browser you're testing with doesn't have the basic auth credentials, or the connection isn't coming from a `10.0` address? (Is there a proxy in front of this server?)

Comment: I'm using a private window on my smartphone to test.  There could be a proxy, but I'm not sure.  I'll try to check the server logs to see where my smartphone request is coming from.

Comment: Damn, it's proxied.  Do you have any alternative solutions for what I want to accomplish in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have your proxy set a header like `X-Forwarded-For` (which might already be set, depending on what's doing the proxying), then use it for the access control check instead, as covered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/235648/apache-use-x-forwarded-for-for-allow).

Something like this..

```
Require valid-user
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For 10\.0\.\d+\.\d+$ proxy_env
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=proxy_env
Satisfy any
```